# None of the exec related PHP functions work under Android

Tags: php, android

I try to crosscompile PHP (trying many versions. now working with 5.3.8) for Android (Android 2.3.3 and Android 4.0.4. Error present in both.). Almost everything is working fine. The most important function for me is executing some shell commands but it does not work! For example this code

```
<?php
    $s = shell_exec("ps");
    echo $s;
?>
```

must output all started processes but in fact displays a blank screen. I try many variants with functions system(), pasthru() and others. All in vain. In php.ini disable_functions empty, safemode off.

In the Internet I found that there is an error with popen() function related to Android OS. But how do I fix this problem?! 
I also found this: [all exec related PHP functions segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922517/all-exec-related-php-functions-segfault?answertab=votes#tab-top)

This is similar to my case. But for some reasons the author does not write how he corrected the error.

**UPDATE:** I think I know what is wrong. This link helped me: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60081 . PHP use for exec commands "/bin/sh" but on Android there is no "/bin/sh". "sh" is located in "/system/bin/sh". I try to copy  "/system/bin/sh" -> "/bin/sh" and all work properly. But now there's a new question. How to tell PHP where "sh" is?

Comment: what are the specs for the platform? which php version?

Comment: Did you check the php.ini setting `disable_functions`. It is only good practice to disable all those functions for security reasons.

Comment: PHP v5.3.8, disable_functions empty, safemode off. Android 2.3.8 and Android 4.0.4. Error present in both.