# PHP : Impossible to exec() under Android

Tags: php, android, shell

I'm willing to develop a small webapp on my android (rooted, 4.2.2) smartphone. The app is designed in PHP to run on a local network.
To do so, i installed KickWeb Server app on the phone from the Play Store. PHP works well yet I'm unable to use any of the functions related to exec (system, passthru, shell_exec).

Apparently, it is a reccurent problem when programming on Android platform due to unusual location of the shell. (/system/bin/sh instead of traditionnal /bin/sh).

Someone had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487637/none-of-the-exec-related-php-functions-work-under-android) so I checked php.ini : safe mode is off and there are no deactivated functions.
Then I tried the suggested workaround by symlinking /system/bin/sh to /bin/sh and trying to fix ownership/permissions, i still got nothing...
Here's my PHP test file :

```
  <?php echo "hello world";
  $out = system('date');
  echo $out; ?>
```

It results in hello world and nothing else, no error.
I'm sure I must have missed somthing yet I can't figure out what. I'm not that familiar with developping under Android.
I hope you guys have a clue, thanks.

Edit : After rebooting the phone, I noticed the /bin folder and /bin/sh symlink had been removed... I don't understand. Here are the steps I followed to create them :

```
mount -o rw,remount,rw /
mkdir /bin
ln -s /system/bin/sh /bin/sh
chmod 777 /bin/sh
chown shell /bin/sh
```

I also tried copying whole /system/bin directory to /bin, doesn't work better.

Maybe I should've posted in Android enthusiast community. I'm not quite sure though, sorry for the mess.

Comment: what does this give you? system('date'); echo $?;

Comment: It results in an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/index.php on line 1

Comment: @user1506104 did I miss something ? what's $? supposed to do anyway ?

Comment: it tells you if the previous command executed without error. at least in linux command line, that's how it works.

Comment: @user1506104 ok that's what i thought, then it should be executed within system() function, and not afterwards, otherwise it's calling PHP's echo. Something like system("date ; echo $?"); should work. Yet it doesn't output anything.

Comment: anyone ? i need help on this one guys

Comment: are you not allowed to use the date (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function from php? let php handle the date for you instead of getting the date yourselft straight from shell.

Comment: in fact i don't need the date function, it was just an example for testing purposes of the exec function

Comment: can you tell me what it is you are trying to achieve? I myself never had any success of shell commands in my Android app.

Comment: well the idea is to remotely play music on the phone : from any device on my local network, i access the local web page hosted on the phone, which triggers via PHP a shell command to play any audio file.